# JavaScript Display/Hide Fields not working - OnChange doesn't occur everytime

Tags: php, javascript, drop-down-menu

```
I am trying to hide and show fields based of the selection in a dropdown field. I got it do hide but when I select another value it doesn't display again.

<script type="text/javacript">
        function checkEm(){
            if (document.getElementById('JobTypeDDL').selected = "2"){
                document.getElementById('DateTbx').style.visibility = "hidden";
                document.getElementById('DateTbx').style.display = "none";
            } else {
                document.getElementById('DateTbx').style.visibility = "visible";
                document.getElementById('DateTbx').style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script>

    <div class="InputField">
        <select name="JobTypeDDL" id="JobTypeDDL" onChange="checkEm()">
            <option value="0" <?php if ($_POST['JobTypeDDL'] == "0") {echo "selected='selected'";} ?> >Select Job Type</option>
            <option value="1" <?php if ($_POST['JobTypeDDL'] == "1") {echo "selected='selected'";} ?> >New Mobility</option>
            <option value="2" <?php if ($_POST['JobTypeDDL'] == "2") {echo "selected='selected'";} ?> >Service/Repair/Install</option>
        </select>
    </div>

<input name="DateTbx" id="DateTbx" type="text" <?php if (!$_POST['DateTbx'] == "") {echo "value='". $_POST['DateTbx']."'";} ?> />
```

Comment: if you don't update your code to *current* code (Kolinks fix) people will likely keep reporting on it.

Comment: also, cache your variables. reaching into the DOM with document.getBy each time is costly. local variables are not.

Answer (score 0):

Use `==` to test equality in an `if` statement. You are using `=`, which is assignment.

Answer (score 0):

In the if condition you're using a single =.  Use  `===` instead.